Menu Files Workspace missing in Blender 4.2.4
Working on my simple one object model, and then notice that the Files Workspace is not seen in the Menu bar by default.  See screenshot showing FILES WORKSPACE in top menu bar for a prior model created in Blender. Try to add or access via right mouse click on Menu bar and the Files Workspace is not listed under General or any of other headings listing in the dropdown menu.  Attempted the three horizontal bar route and still no Files Workspace.  Also understand that Shift + F should access the Files Workspace but during so opens nothing. The object has an assigned material and is with UV mapping done. Any suggestions on how to access the Files Workspace.

Not really sure what you mean by 'Files Workspace'? Do you mean the File / Edit / Render / Window / Help Menus are missing? If so, right-click on the menu bar and check 'Show Menus' under the bottom Header entry. If that's not what you mean please add an image of your Blender window to your question.

At the very top is the Menu Bar with tags for like Layout, Modeling, Sculpting, UV Editing, Etc., if I LMC the + the dropdown menus appear, but Files is not under any of the Tags like General, 2D Animation, Etc.

The 'File' menu entry is part of the main menu not one of the layout options as I said in my comment above. Please add an image of your Blender window as I asked above editing it into your question so that we can see exactly what you're talking about.

There never was a "file" workspace. (see docs) What do you expect to get? The file menu? See above. The file browser? That's an editor, not a workspace.

Maybe you renamed an existing workspace, but again: there are no "file" workspace.
